# Im having another problem with my code the error is "redefinition of 'AF_DCMotor motor'?

Tags: arduino-mega, adafruit, sketch, arduino-motor-shield, error

Heres the code

```
#include <AFMotor.h>

AF_DCMotor motor(1, MOTOR12_8KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor(2, MOTOR12_8KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor(3, MOTOR34_1KHZ);

void setup()  {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.printIn("Motor Test!");
  motor1.setSpeed(15); //set speed of motor
  motor2.setSpeed(15); //set speed of motor
  motor3.setSpeed(15); //set speed of motor

}
void loop() {
  Serial.print("tick");
  motor1.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor1.run(RELEASE);
  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("tack"); //first song starts 
  motor1.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);


  Serial.print("tock");
  motor1.run(RELEASE);
  delay(9000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor1.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //first song ends
  motor1.run(RELEASE);
  delay(20000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor1.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick"); 
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor1.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor1.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

   Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor1.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //first song stops
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(14000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //first song stops
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  delay(11000);

  Serial.print("tick"); //first song stops
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  delay(22000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //first song stops
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  delay(19000);
}
```

Here is the error:

```
   ^~~~~~

   motor

snowmanDC_Motor:13:3: error: 'motor3' was not declared in this scope

   motor3.setSpeed(15); //set speed of motor

   ^~~~~~

C:\Users\serluca\Documents\Arduino\snowmanDC_Motor\snowmanDC_Motor.ino:13:3: note: suggested alternative: 'motor'

   motor3.setSpeed(15); //set speed of motor

   ^~~~~~

   motor

C:\Users\serluca\Documents\Arduino\snowmanDC_Motor\snowmanDC_Motor.ino: In function 'void loop()':

snowmanDC_Motor:18:3: error: 'motor1' was not declared in this scope

   motor1.run(FORWARD);

   ^~~~~~

C:\Users\serluca\Documents\Arduino\snowmanDC_Motor\snowmanDC_Motor.ino:18:3: note: suggested alternative: 'motor'

   motor1.run(FORWARD);

   ^~~~~~

   motor

snowmanDC_Motor:47:3: error: 'motor2' was not declared in this scope

   motor2.run(FORWARD);

   ^~~~~~

C:\Users\serluca\Documents\Arduino\snowmanDC_Motor\snowmanDC_Motor.ino:47:3: note: suggested alternative: 'motor'

   motor2.run(FORWARD);

   ^~~~~~

   motor

snowmanDC_Motor:115:3: error: 'motor3' was not declared in this scope

   motor3.run(RELEASE);

   ^~~~~~

C:\Users\serluca\Documents\Arduino\snowmanDC_Motor\snowmanDC_Motor.ino:115:3: note: suggested alternative: 'motor'

   motor3.run(RELEASE);

   ^~~~~~

   motor

exit status 1
redefinition of 'AF_DCMotor motor'
```

Comment: Do you have V1 or V2 shield? They have different library.

Comment: @Tommy, you are still at it ... congratulations for not giving up .... I can tell you right now, you will have a long battle until you tell us what hardware you have and how you connected it

Comment: You consistently fail to use libraries that you have installed. Or you are *sure* you have installed. Instead of repeatedly throwing the same code at us with a different library you should instead take a step back and look more into how you are going about installing libraries and why, maybe, the IDE can't find them.  https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/libraries

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106212/discussion-on-question-by-tommy-im-having-another-problem-with-my-code-the-error).

Answer (score 1):

Adafruit has a V1 and a V2 motor shield. They have different libraries too. AFMotor.h is for the V1 shield. From the error, I can tell you installed V2 lib. For that you need to include:

```
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
```

Comment: I needed to install the Adafruit v1 library Thanks for the help tho, Im new to all of this stuff. but now its saying another error "redefinition of 'AF_DCMotor'

Comment: I fixed the question to the new question, the new error is in there too

Comment: On line 3,4, and 5, you used same name "motor" for all three instances. Changed those to motor1, motor2, and motor3